# Not able to install notepadqq

Tags: unix, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to linux, I have messed up my workstation and when i tried to install notepadqq i got this error. please anyone help me out.

```
th1588@th1588-ThinkCentre-M73:~/tools/confluent-3.3.1$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in 
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in 
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You should ask this question to [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead of SO.

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution can be found here:

[add-apt-repository...](https://qiita.com/miyagaw61/items/665616d769f74158f1a1)

Enter commands below and everything will be find:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,36m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```